# How to combine two arrays with some operators?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, operators

I have two arrays like below,

```
var arr1 = [false, true, false];

var arr2 = [And, Or, null];
```

Now i make this two array with operator exchange.

And replace with &&
Or replace with ||

Is this possible to acheive?

**Now I expected result is**

```
var result = false && true || false;

if(result){
// when result true, 
}

else{
// when result false
}
```

Please suggest your answer!!!

Comment: What is `And` and `Or` ? What have you tried?!

Comment: SImple! I have two array. one is bool, another one is operator. I need to combine both with exchange of operator like And (&&), Or (||).

Comment: I understood your problem. The questions code is still invalid, have a look at [mcve], and its unclear what you've tried to solve the problem.

Comment: how do you decide result `false && true || false;` can you explain this ?

Comment: @GokulKumar Yes I see that's not make sense to create logic. your question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

It will work only if arr1 and arr2 will satify these two condition

> 1. arr2 should only two type's of value 'And' and 'Or'
> 2. length of arr2 should be arr1.length-1

```js
var arr1 = [false, true, false];

var arr2 = ['And', 'Or', null];

arr2 = arr2.map(val => {
    val = val == "And" ? "&&" : val;
    val = val == "Or" ? "||" : val;
    return val;
})


var resultantArray = arr1.reduce((obj, val, index) => {

    obj.push(val);
    if (arr2[index] && index < arr1.length - 1)
        obj.push(arr2[index]);
    return obj
}, []);

var resultantCondition = resultantArray.join(" ");
console.log(resultantCondition);

if (eval(resultantCondition))
    console.log(true);

else
    console.log(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, But this output consider as a string. For example you can check the if condition, it returns always true.

Comment: `it returns always true` means? With above sample It is going in false condition, If you use `var arr2 = ['Or', 'Or', null];` this array then you will get true.

Answer (score 0):

You could strings for the operands and an object for collecting all operators and reduce the array with the values by getting the function of the same index anf return the value of the function call.

```js
var fn = { and: (a, b) => a && b, or: (a, b) => a && b, identity: a => a },
    operands = [false, true, false],
    operators = ['and', 'or', null],
    result = operands.reduce((a, b, i) => (fn[operators[i]] || fn.identity)(a, b));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the precedence is the given order.

Comment: `true && false || false && true` will be `false` if you follow boolean algebra.

Comment: operands = [false, true, false],
operators = ['or', 'or', null], 
It gives as false. But actually it should return true.